# How should I understand below regex

Tags: regex

```
/\(\d{3})*\d{4}*\d{4}/
```

I understand most of what the symbols mean, so I'll put here what I think that line will match with, then please correct me if I'm wrong anywhere.

I will first break this regex into three parts:

- `\(\d{3})*`
- `\d{4}*`
- `\d{4}`

Part one will match with any three digits any number of times. For strings like 8456328, this regex will match with 845 and 632. However, I don't understand the starting escape character and its functionality.

The second part, I'm pretty confident, means it will match any four digits any number of times. So for string 3452345, 3452 will be a match.

The third part will only match four digits. So 1234 or 5678, or 1029.

So all combined, a string like 123123123412345678 will be a match.

That's how I understand it, but it feels really wrong because, from my lecture notes, this regex is supposed to represent a telephone number so please correct me wherever I've made a mistake.

Comment: What flavour of regex is this? This doesn't seem valid to me. At the very least the brackets are unbalanced.

Comment: Yeah, looks dodgy. Are you saying it actually works? In what? I would expect the second part would need a capture group too - like `(\d{4})*`. And the initial \ also looks wrong.

Comment: Could it be that the asterisks are actually spaces? If you exclude the first \, that would then be valid - ie. `(\d{3}) \d{4} \d{4}`.

Comment: Next time I have a lab I will ask him about it I guess, thanks for letting me know this is wrong so I don't need to waste more brain power trying to figure this out at least.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/m3hdxm/1

Comment: This Website's actually a god send for regex @Toto, thanks man